# Wireless mouse lags on high CPU usage

Tags: 14.04, wireless, mouse, cpu-load

I sure hope this is a novel problem as I have tried to find a solution to it every time I get really fed up with this, which has been quite a few times, but no luck so far.

Trouble is that when my CPU is under heavy load then my wireless mouse (HP Z4000) starts to lag a LOT.

The strange thing is that if I move the mouse closer to the receiver on the PC, the lag goes away. It's not a solution though, because when I say closer, I mean about 10-15cm from the receiver, which is not feasible when trying to use a laptop with an external monitor, a mouse and keyboard attached.

Also the touchpad works just fine. For example if I load a huge file the wireless mouse refuses to cooperate until either the file has finished loading or I close it using keyboard or touchpad, which remain usable.
I have tried with all four USB ports (2x2.0, 2x3.0) and the problem persists.

Is it possible, that high CPU load draws power from the USB ports so the signal strength weakens?

I'm using an HP Elitebook G840(i5-4200U, 4GB RAM) and Ubuntu 14.04.

Anything else I should add here that would help?

Comment: very frustrating that 8 years later we're still having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing on my desktop computer with a Logitech mouse.  In my case, I think it was temperature related.  High CPU usage caused everything connected to the motherboard to heat up.  When I connected the receiver to the far end of a USB extension cord, the problem went away.

Comment: I actually did the same thing, but this seems more like a hack than a solution. Might be the best we'll get though.
I'd figure that in my case it's not heat related either, because sometimes it works just fine under heavy load and if it decides to start lagging it starts right with the high load. I'd suppose that if it was heat related it'd take a bit to heat things up.
I'm no specialist though. Obviously.